# Date_sub() on a date array

Tags: php

I am trying to remove exactly 1 year from every date of an array.

Here is the original $periods array

```
Array ( [0] => 2020-06-01 [1] => 2020-07-01 [2] => 2020-08-01 [3] => 2020-09-01 [4] => 2021-01-01 [5] => 2022-01-01 [6] => 2022-06-01 [7] => 2022-08-01 [8] => 2022-10-01 [9] => 2023-04-01 )
```

I tried

```
foreach ($periods as $p) {
date_sub($p,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 year"));
echo date_format($p,"Y-m-d"). '<br>';
}
```

It doesn't return anything...
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the data types in your array? Are these strings? If these were DateTimes you would have no issue.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber the type is Date not Datetime...is that an issue?

Comment: There's no Date type in PHP. What Dirk means is that it's hard to do maths with strings, you're better off using Unix time (`int`) or `DateTime` objects.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Sorry `date' was displaying as the type in the Mysql table structure I am fecthing from

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase It seems my code was not wrong but my source dates were strings, that's why the date_sub function was not returning. Once converted to a date object it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set your array values datatype to string => "2020-06-01" , and try this code:

```
foreach ($periods as $period) {
// convert date string to date model object
$periodDate = date_create($period); 
// subtract date string from coverted date string
date_sub($periodDate,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 year"));
// covert subtracted date object to readable date fromat
echo date_format($periodDate,"Y-m-d");
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @just code Thanks, I have to leave now but will try that tonight after work and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

You can transform dates using next code:

```
$res = array_map(
    // convert source string to time, subtract 1 year interval
    // and convert to 'Y-m-d' format in singe function

    fn($p) => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year", strtotime($p))),
    $periods
);
```

[run PHP online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/e79c689549c81cf36e4241eb2df1ac25/)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase, sure. Already commented